# How do I create a keypair using a custom derivation path with Javascript?

Tags: web3.js, keypair, private-key

I have a seed phrase that I used to generate an address with and sent tokens to it. I entered the seed phrase into Solflare wallet but it can't find the address with tokens on it.

How do I create a keypair using a **custom derivation path** so I can perform transactions with it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Using Javascript

This can be done with the `ed25519-hd-key` and `tweetnacl` libraries.

Make sure you start the path with `m/44'/501'`, as this is required for Solana addresses.

Setup (run this in your terminal):

```
npm init -y && npm i @solana/web3.js bip39 tweetnacl buffer ed25519-hd-key
```

Create a file with this code and run it with `node <FILENAME.js>`:

```
import { Keypair } from '@solana/web3.js';
import * as bip39 from 'bip39';
import nacl from 'tweetnacl';
import { Buffer } from 'buffer';
import * as ed25519 from 'ed25519-hd-key';

// Replace with your mnemonic
const mnemonic = 'cabbage together debris chalk hammer novel wire tunnel rubber labor retire prefer';

// Convert the mnemonic to a seed
const seed = bip39.mnemonicToSeedSync(mnemonic).slice(0, 32);

// Define the derivation path
const path = `m/44'/501'/0'/0'`; // Replace with your custom path

// Derive a seed from the given path
const derivedSeed = ed25519.derivePath(path, Buffer.from(seed, 'hex')).key;

// Generate a keypair from the derived seed using tweetnacl (NaCl = Networking and Cryptography library)
const derivedUint8Keypair = nacl.sign.keyPair.fromSeed(derivedSeed);

// This is a Uint8Array, not a Solana web3.js Keypair object, so you will need to convert it
const customPathKeypair = Keypair.fromSecretKey(
  Uint8Array.from(derivedUint8Keypair.secretKey)
);

console.log('Custom Path Keypair address:', customPathKeypair.publicKey.toBase58());
```

#### Using wallets

The Backpack wallet supports [arbitrary derivation paths](https://twitter.com/armaniferrante/status/1742421810367611046), so you can just import your seed phrase into it and set the path.

https://backpack.app/downloads

Comment: Open to improvements or ways this can be done better!